# File uploads to another directory other than spcified directory in PHP code

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a folder struct like this:

```
 admin-panel
     -- thesis-scripts
           -- add_thesis.php 
 uploads
```

And I am trying to upload a .docx file to the uploads directory. Here is my code:

```
$targ_dir = "uploads/";
$targ_file = "../" . $targ_dir . basename($_FILES["thesisfile"]["name"]);
$flagOk = 1;
$tempFolder = $_FILES['thesisfile']['tmp_name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($tempFolder, urlencode($targ_file))){
    echo $targ_file;
}
```

However, the code above results to a file upload inside the `thesis-scripts` folder. How can I move the file to the `uploads` folder? Thanks for the help. I purposely added the `../` in the `$targ_file` because I will save the file path in the database.

Answer (score 0):

`upload_tmp_dir` is what you need, to change the default temporary directory, According to the documentation [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir)

> upload_tmp_dir string The temporary directory used for storing files
>   when doing file upload. Must be writable by whatever user PHP is
>   running as. If not specified PHP will use the system's default.
>
> If the directory specified here is not writable, PHP falls back to the
>   system default temporary directory. If open_basedir is on, then the
>   system default directory must be allowed for an upload to succeed.

You have 2 choices either  write it in your php code:

```
ini_set('upload_tmp_dir','your/path');
```

or change it in the php.ini uncomment `upload_tmp_dir` and eventually use the path needed

Comment: I tried that one too, but it didn't work for me. @яша

Answer (score 0):

Change $target_dir to be "/uploads" (note the leading slash).

Without the leading slash, uploads is relative to the script, with the leading slash it is relative to the top of the directory

Comment: Didn't work for me. :( I tried `/uploads` and `/uploads/` but did not work. @user2182349

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your replies guys. I managed to solve it by using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . /path/path`

```
//$targ_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ThesisRepo/uploads/';
$targ_file = $targ_dir  . basename($_FILES["thesisfile"]["name"]);
$flagOk = 1;
$tempFolder = $_FILES['thesisfile']['tmp_name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($tempFolder, $targ_file)){
    // echo $_FILES["thesisfile"]["name"]; 
    echo $targ_file;
    //echo basename($_FILES["thesisfile"]["name"]); 
}
```